# Filter models on the basis of dictionary key

Tags: django, python-3.6, mongoengine

I am facing a problem while filtering a record from the database. In my database I have records which contain a dictfield.

for eg
region is a dictionary which contains other dictionaries like

`region = {'eastus': {'percentage_change': 0}, 'westus': {'percentage_change': 0}}`

and I want to fetch `eastus` or `westus`.

I have tried something like this, but I am getting an empty list.

`MyModel.objects.filter(region__eq='eastus')`

any suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this with the `exists` operator (http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#query-operators)

```
MyModel.objects.filter(region__eastus__exists=True)
```

Regarding the OR, you should use the `Q` class (http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries), thus:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(region__eastus__exists=True) | Q(region__westus__exists=True))
```

If you have keys that aren't simple (e.g including fancy character or simply a dash), you can use the __raw__ operator:

`MyModel.objects.filter(__raw__={'region.a-fancy-key': {'$exists': True}})`